# Web scraping shows 403 error but website is available

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape CS2 skin prices from https://pricempire.com/search?q=ursus. From Inspect in Chrome I find https://api.pricempire.com/v2/search/items?page=1&priceMin=0&priceMax=1000000&orderBy=price_desc&priceProvider=gamerpay&q=ursus&attr1=undefined&attr2=undefined&appId=730 where in Console I see the information needed but when I try to scrape the site, it says 403.

I use the following code based on other answers
([Web scraping results in 403 Forbidden Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48756326/web-scraping-results-in-403-forbidden-error)) where people see a 403 error only when web scraping:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

# URL of the webpage to scrape
url = 'https://api.pricempire.com/v2/search/items?page=1&priceMin=0&priceMax=1000000&orderBy=price_desc&priceProvider=gamerpay&q=ursus&attr1=undefined&attr2=undefined&appId=730'  # Replace with the URL of the page you want to scrape

headers = {
    "authority": "api.pricempire.com",
    "method":"GET",
    "Sec-Ch-Ua":'"Google Chrome";v="119", "Chromium";v="119", "Not?A_Brand";v="24"',
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/119.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",
    "Cookie":"_ym_uid=1690206513662695582; _ym_d=1690206513; google-analytics_v4_lTnF__ga4=60b6fd6e-a42c-4a5b-86a3-b2ee4112ff43; google-analytics_v4_lTnF___z_ga_audiences=60b6fd6e-a42c-4a5b-86a3-b2ee4112ff43; _ga_8Q07ZHZ839=GS1.1.1698572129.62.1.1698572431.60.0.0; _ga=GA1.1.682725627.1690206513; _ym_isad=1; cf_clearance=586R0lbtXGfr_0eAxZ6FQGhjOP8KbabV9ausTZQV0J4-1701790159-0-1-5b5ce1f2.48e600da.934cebb0-0.2.1701790159; google-analytics_v4_lTnF__ga4sid=1266105687; google-analytics_v4_lTnF__session_counter=23; _ym_visorc=w; google-analytics_v4_lTnF__engagementPaused=1701799553646; google-analytics_v4_lTnF__engagementStart=1701799554306; google-analytics_v4_lTnF__counter=851; google-analytics_v4_lTnF__let=1701799554306; _ga_5YMSVJKHTZ=GS1.1.1701798361.82.1.1701799556.58.0.0"
}

# Send a GET request to the URL
r = requests.get(url, headers = headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
print(r)
```

My current output is:

```
<Response [403]>
```

How can I bypass this?

Comment: There are rules for accessing their API.  https://pricempire.com/assets/api-terms.html

Comment: Hi @TimRoberts! Thanks for the highlight. Do you believe it is possible to access this data without the API?

Comment: Why would you want to?  You would be violating their copyright.  They have generously provided an API, you just need to be authorized.  So, get authorized.  What's the big deal?

Comment: your link to api gives me `"Access denied"`. It may need to login or some special authorization. Page also use JavaScript to get data - so it may also use it to check if you are real human (with real browser which can run JavaScript). If they have money then they can create more complex system to detect scripts - and it may need to use [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/)  and proxy servers (and they may need to be paid because free proxy servers often are detected and blocked)