Error 403 while fetching data using Google Apps Script
I am trying to make a request using Urlfetchapp, this has been working fine for a month but now it starts giving an Error 403 message. The sample code is:
function fetchWithRetry() {
 
  var url = 'https://www.futbin.com/25/player/55430/robin-koch'; //sample url

  for (var attempt = 0; attempt < 4; attempt++) {
    try {
      var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
      return result.getContentText();  // If successful, return the result
    } catch (error) {
      Logger.log("Attempt " + (attempt + 1) + " failed for URL: " + url + ". Error: " + error);  // Wait before retrying
    }
  }
  return null;  // If all attempts fail, return null
} 

The error looks like this:

https://www.futbin.com/25/player/55430/robin-koch. Error: Exception:
Request failed for https://www.futbin.com returned code 403. Truncated
server response: Just a
moment...<meta htt... (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine
full response)

Following this question, I tried adding headers in the request:
   var url = 'https://www.futbin.com/25/player/55430/robin-koch'; //sample url
   var headers = {
    "authority": "www.futbin.com",
    "method": "GET",
    "referer": "https://www.google.com/",
    "sec-ch-ua": "\"Google Chrome\";v=\"129\", \"Not=A?Brand\";v=\"8\", \"Chromium\";v=\"129\"",
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/547.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/127.0.0.0 Safari/547.36"
  };
  
  var options = {
    "method": "GET",
    "headers": headers,
    "muteHttpExceptions": true
  };

 var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,options);

But it did not work out either. Can we use a proxy in the request header as mentioned in this answer? I am trying to get the following values from the webpage as a result, I would appreciate any workaround to resolve this:


It is entirely possible they have a monthly request limit.  Have you checked their site?

I am unsure if there is any request limit because I am not using their API. I am just getting publicly available data from the fetch response

Whether you call it one or not, you're using their site as an API.  That web site is copyrighted, so they may have a request limit to protect their intellectual property.

According this article , The HTTP 403 Forbidden client error response status code indicates that the server understood the request but refused to process it. This status is similar to 401, except that for 403 Forbidden responses, authenticating or re-authenticating makes no difference. The request failure is tied to application logic, such as insufficient permissions to a resource or action. You might want to consider looking for documentation about accessing the given website

It worked fine until today, I am not sure what has changed in a day. I have updated my question with the required values to get from webpage

I tried your code and I get something like "wait a moment..." page, this could mean page restrictions like Captcha, I also tried accessing https://www.futbin.com/robots.txt, you can learn more about robots.txt here https://developers.google.com/search/docs/crawling-indexing/robots/intro#:~:text=A%20robots.txt%20file%20tells,web%20page%20out%20of%20Google.
I don't totally understand what the output of https://www.futbin.com/robots.txt is but most likely, web crawling is disallow on the site.

The website seems to have enabled ip based blocking. All  public vpn ip, aws, gcp ips seems to be blocked. You need a unblocked ip as proxy, if this needs to work.

may be if we use cookies or any specific credential in the header of the fetch request to resolve the issue

I don't think that's possible. I get 403 in my browser(which sends cookies etc by default), if I use a vpn. However, I don't have a account there... so maybe if you have account and send credentials, but the chances of that are extremely low as this seems to be a blanket ban on ips

About I would appreciate any workaround to resolve this:, in your situation, using the languages except for Google Apps Script is included in any workaround?

I am trying to get data in Google Sheets, so my preferred language is Google Apps Script

Can we use a proxy in the request header mentioned in this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48756326/web-scraping-results-in-403-forbidden-error?noredirect=1&lq=1
